# Test PresentedViewController with XCTest

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7, xctest

I have method which I would like to test:

```
- (void)sendMailToContact:(Contact *)conact
{
    self.contact = conact;

    if ([self isSendingAvaiable]) {

        MFMailComposeViewController *mailViewController = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
        mailViewController.mailComposeDelegate = self;
        [mailViewController setToRecipients:@[self.contact.email]];

        [self.parentViewController presentViewController:mailViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
    }
}
```

The test...

```
- (void)testSendMailToContact_itShouldShowMFMailComposeViewController
{
    UIViewController *mockViewController = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
    [mockViewController viewDidLoad];

    MailComposer *mockMailComposer = [MailComposer sharedComposerWithController:mockViewController];

    [mockMailComposer sendMailToContact:[self mockContact]];

    XCTAssertTrue([mockViewController.presentedViewController isKindOfClass:[MFMailComposeViewController class]], @"");
}
```

But It not work correctly. I should have MFMailComposeViewController as presentedViewController but I have null. I don't know what to do. Please help!

Comment: Try `[mockViewController view];` instead of `viewDidLoad`.

Comment: Changing [mockViewController viewDidLoad] on [mockViewController view] didn't help

Answer (score 11):

The problem is that `mockViewController` is not in `UIWindow` hierarchy. Try:

```
[UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow.rootViewController = mockViewController;
```

Then you can also get rid of `viewDidLoad` call.

Comment: Works for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

Add your root ViewController instance to a UIWindow before testing, no need to use `UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController` as mentioned above.

```
let window = UIWindow()
window.rootViewController = yourRootViewController
window.makeKeyAndVisible()


XCTAssert(yourRootViewController.presentedViewController is YourModalViewController)
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's the Swift 4 solution:

```
let vc = UIViewController()
UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController = vc
```

In your test…

```
XCTAssert(vc.presentedViewController is MyCustomViewController)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your test case contains some issues.
You are presenting the `MFMailComposeViewController` from `MailComposer`. So you should call the `presentedViewController` on `mockMailComposer` not on `mockViewController`.

Change that to:

```
- (void)testSendMailToContact_itShouldShowMFMailComposeViewController
{
    MailComposer *mockMailComposer = [MailComposer sharedComposerWithController:mockViewController];

    [mockMailComposer sendMailToContact:[self mockContact]];

    XCTAssertTrue([mockMailComposer.presentedViewController isKindOfClass:[MFMailComposeViewController class]], @"");
}
```

Comment: presentedViewController is still nill

Answer (score 0):

It  looks as though you need 2 parts to your test (or 2 separate tests).  The first part should ensure that `isSendingAvaiable` is `NO` and test that `mockViewController.presentedViewController` is `nil`.  The second part should ensure that `isSendingAvaiable` is `YES` and test that `mockViewController.presentedViewController` is of the appropriate class.

When a test fails it is important to determine whether the fault lies with the code being testing or with the test itself.

Perhaps the issue is that `isSendingAvaiable` is `NO`.